# how to give @readonly in DropdownListfor in asp.net MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

Even if adding `@readonly`to `DropDownListFor` user can still select from dropdown.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ItemId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ddlItem, "-- Select Item --", new { id = "ddlItem", @class = "form-control" **@readonly = "readonly"** })
```

How to stop that?

Comment: A `<select>` element does not have a `readonly` attribute. Just generate a readonly textbox

Comment: Thanks - Stephen Muecke